Connecting PowerBI to MongoDB Atlas
Is it possible to connect PowerBI to MongoDB Atlas (cloud) without on-premises data gateway?
The semantic model is created with PowerBI Desktop with "MongoDB Atlas SQL" data source, which seems to be the only way to get data from MongoDB.
I have published the model to Power BI online. Going into semantic model settings -> "Gateway and cloud connections" I see "Use an On-premises or VNet data gateway" On and greyed out.
I then have tried to create "MongoDB Atlas for Pipelines" cloud connection but it does not appear in "Gateway and cloud connections" for the semantic model as an option.
Is there a way to configure periodic refresh of MongoDB Atlas data source in the semantic model published to Power BI online without the on-premises data gateway?

It's the other way around. For Atlas you don't need any gateway. Just install the ODBC Driver and connect. For On-premises you need to install the MongoDB BI Connector On Atlas you can define the schema refresh interval in seconds
